# Hooking up a second monitor using a USB-(Displayport/HDMI/VGA) adapter

Tags: linux, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have `Asus k401uq` using `Ubuntu 20.04` - xorg driver (although I have an Nvidia graphic card but I'm not using Nvidia driver), the laptop comes with HDMI output for display which I'm already using.
I want to use a second monitor. I can do it probably by using some sort of adapter to USB.
I've done some research to figure out whether my hardware support a second video display but I'm stuck.

`lsusb` command show the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58ee Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The third line says `USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam` does this mean I can get a USB 2.0 to VGA adapter and it will work? and if it does do I have to install Nvidia driver ?

Comment: See also: [Ask Ubuntu: USB to HDMI adapter that works with 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1322169/327339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lsusb shows **Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub**, so your laptop supports USB 3.0, and you can connect any of USB-A to [HDMI/VGA adapters based on USB-DisplayLINK technology](https://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-adapters). It won't be "gaming-fast", but good enough to watch news and stock charts.

You can find similar adapters even in USB 2.0 technology node.

Comment: You got [my research started on DisplayLink](https://askubuntu.com/a/1486986/327339), which looks very promising. Thank you. I'm buying a USB 3.0 to HDMI DisplayLink adapter now.